# How do I make my regex match whitespaces without consuming them?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match lines that contains chords, but I need to make sure each match is surrounded by whitespace or first in line without consuming the characters as I don't want them returned to the caller.

E.g.

```
Standard Tuning (Capo on fifth fret)

Time signature: 12/8
Tempo: 1.5 * Quarter note = 68 BPM

Intro: G Em7 G Em7

  G                 Em7
I heard there was a secret chord
     G                   Em7
That David played and it pleased the lord
    C                D              G/B     D
But you don't really care for music, do you? 
        G/B                C          D
Well it goes like this the fourth, the fifth
    Em7                 C
The minor fall and the major lift
    D            B7/D#         Em
The baffled king composing hallelujah

Chorus:

G/A   G/B  C           Em         C             G/B   D/A    G
Hal - le-  lujah, hallelujah, hallelujah, hallelu-u-u-u-jah ....
```

Almost works except it also matches the "B" in "68 BPM". Now how do I make sure that chords are correctly matched? I don't want it to match the B in Before or the D or E in SUBSIDE?

This is my algorithm for matching on each separate line:

```
function getChordMatches(line) {
    var pattern = /[ABCDEFG](?:#|##|b|bb)?(?:min|m)?(?:maj|add|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]*(?:\/[ABCDEFG](?:#|##|b|bb)?)?/g;
    var chords = line.match(pattern);
    var positions = [];
    while ((match = pattern.exec(line)) != null) {
        positions.push(match.index);
    }

    return {
        "chords":chords,
        "positions":positions
    };
}
```

That is I want arrays on the form ["A", "Bm", "C#"] and not [" A", "Bm ", " C# "].

**edit**

I made it work using the accepted answer. I had to make some adjustments to accomodate the leading whitespaces. Thanks for taking the time everyone!

```
function getChordMatches(line) {
    var pattern = /(?:^|\s)[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?(?:min|m)?(?:maj|add|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]*(?:\/[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?)?(?!\S)/g;
    var chords = line.match(pattern);
    var chordLength = -1;
    var positions = [];

    while ((match = pattern.exec(line)) != null) {
        positions.push(match.index);
    }

    for (var i = 0; chords && i < chords.length; i++) {
        chordLength = chords[i].length;
        chords[i] = chords[i].trim();
        positions[i] -= chords[i].length - chordLength;
    }

    return {
        "chords":chords,
        "positions":positions
    };
}
```

Comment: Aside from your white space issue, are you sure that pattern is adequate? What about chords like F13#11 or C7b9 or G11no3rd?

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right. It will not match those chords. However, I've never encountered anything like that (are those Jazz chords?) so I'll have to adjust the pattern should I need them.

Comment: Well you're more likely to see weirder chords like those on a jazz chart, but really a chord with a flat 9 isn't that obscure. I've seen things like "E no 3rd" on rock, pop and worship music charts though, sometimes with parentheses as "E(no 3rd)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume that you have split the input into lines already. And the function will process the lines one by one.*

You just need to check that the line has a chord as the first item before extracting them:

```
if (/^\s*[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?(?:min|m)?(?:maj|add|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]*(?:\/[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?)?(?!\S)/.test(line)) {
    // Match the chords here
}
```

I added `^\s*` in front to check from the beginning of the line, and added `(?!\S)` to check that there is a whitespace character `\s` or end of line after the first chord.

Note that I made some minor changes to your regex, since `A##` (assuming it is valid chord) will not be matched by your current regex. The regex engine will check the match by following the order of the patterns in alternation, so `#` will be attempted first in `#|##`. It will find that `A#` matches and return the match without checking for `##`. Either reversing the order `##|#` or use greedy quantifier `##?` fixes the problem, as it checks for the longer alternative first.

---

If you are sure that: "if the first item is a chord, then the rest are chords", then instead of matching, you can just split by spaces:

```
line.split(/\s+/);
```

---

**Update**

If you want to just match your pattern, regardless of whether the chord is inside a sentence (what you currently have will do that):

```
/(?:^|\s)[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?(?:min|m)?(?:maj|add|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]*(?:\/[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?)?(?!\S)/
```

This regex is to be placed in the code you have in your question.

I check that the chord is preceded by whitespace character or is the beginning of the line with `(?:^|\s)`. You need to trim the leading space in the result, though.

Using `\b` instead of `(?:^|\s)` will avoid leading space issue, but the meaning is different. Unless you know the input well enough, I'd advice against it.

---

Another way is to split the string by `\s+`, and test the following regex against each of the token (note the `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end):

```
 /^[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?(?:min|m)?(?:maj|add|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]*(?:\/[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?)?$/
```

Comment: Good point about being able to split on white space once a line with chords has been identified. But why wouldn't the original regex match "A##"?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Due to the regex engine choosing `#` before `##` (it will follow the order in the alternation), it will consider `A#` a match. `##?` with `?` being greedy, or `##|#` will check for `A##` before `A#`, so if you have `A##`, either `##?` or `##|#` will match correctly.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Please check my latest edit. I modified the regex a bit.

Comment: This is a good idea and great input on my current pattern, but I realize I haven't worded my problem correctly as I want the chords in the line "Intro: G Em7 G Em7" to be detected too. I'll edit my question. I'm sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\b` (word boundary) to the start and end works for me.  Also, you can use `A-G` instead of  `ABCDEFG`.  Thus:

```
> re = /\b[A-G](?:#|##|b|bb)?(?:min|m)?(?:maj|add|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]*(?:\/[A-G](?:#|##|b|bb)?)?\b/g
/\b[A-G](?:#|##|b|bb)?(?:min|m)?(?:maj|add|sus|aug|dim)?[0-9]*(?:\/[A-G](?:#|##|b|bb)?)?\b/g

> 'G/A   G/B  C           Em         C             G/B   D/A    G'.match(re)
["G/A", "G/B", "C", "Em", "C", "G/B", "D/A", "G"]

> 'Tempo: 1.5 * Quarter note = 68 BPM'.match(re)
null
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the specific question in the title, use the look ahead :

```
 (?=\s)
```

when embedded in an RE would ensure that the following character was a whitespace without consuming it.

Comment: If the chord is right at the end (no space), it might not work.

Comment: @HBP I've tried that and as mentioned above it fixes the issue, but creates another where chords followed by newline aren't matched.

Comment: @MdaG Why not to add some OR operators?: `(?=\s|\r|\n)`

Comment: @rcdmk I tried that as well (before writing this question) and it didn't take. Besides doesn't \s equal \n|\t|\r ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
function getChordMatches( line ) {
    var match,
        pattern = /(?:^|\s)([A-G](?:##?|bb?)?(?:min|m)?(?:maj|add|sus|aug|dim)?\d*(?:\/[A-G](?:##?|bb?)?)?)(?=$|\s)/g,
        chords = [],
        positions = [];

    while ( match = pattern.exec(line) ) {
        chords.push( match[1] );
        positions.push( match.index );
    }

    return {
        "chords" : chords,
        "positions" : positions
    };
}
```

It uses `(?:^|\s)` to make sure the chord is either at the start of the line or is preceded by a space, and uses the positive look-ahead `(?=$|\s)` to make sure the chord is followed by a space or is at the end of the line. Parentheses are added to capture the chord itself, which is then accessed by `match[1]`.